# Starting via Java an proccess (script/executable) on a remote Linux machine

Tags: java, linux, ssh, remote-access

Is there a way that allows to start form a java (web) application a process on a remote Linux application?

The Java (web) application it self is running on a Linux machine (but windows support would be nice).
It should be possible to run a command on operating system level on a remote Linux machine (Linux only).
Is there a built in possibility for Java to connect using ssh to another host and run a command and get the return-value, stdout, stderr?

Comment: Look at [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ProcessBuilder to run a command using bash as it follows (example using ssh):

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String{"/bin/bash", "-c", "ssh [ssh-options/commands]"});

Process pro = pb.start();
```

Once you have started the process you can the get the outputStream, errorStream and the exitCode from it.

Here's some documentation that may help you:

[Running ssh commands](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-execute-command-using-ssh/)

[ProcessBuilder use examples 1 (including use of Runtime.getRuntime to create a process)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-lang-process-class-java/)

[ProcessBuilder use examples 2](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-processbuilder-examples/)

Hope you find this useful!

Comment: Was not thinking about that one - but is it as well proper for executing on a remote Linux Host?

Comment: You should be able to execute any command that is available on the remote machine via ssh and get it's output using the Process created by ProcessBuilder.